# Select subset of numpy.ndarray based on other array's values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy.ndarrays and I would like to select a subset of Array #2 based on the values in Array #1 (Criteria: Values > 1):

```py
#Array 1 - print(type(result_data):
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
#print(result_data):
[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  ...
  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  1  3  3  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]

#Array #2 - print(type(test_data):
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
#print(test_data):
[[-1.38693584  0.76183275]
 [-1.38685102  0.76187584]
 [-1.3869291   0.76186742]
 ..., 
 [-1.38662322  0.76160456]
 [-1.38662322  0.76160456]
 [-1.38662322  0.76160456]]
```

I tried:

```py
x=0
selArray = np.empty
for i in result_data:
    x+=1
    if i > 1:
         selArray = np.append(selArray,[test_data[x].T[0],test_data[x].T[1]])
```

...but this gives me:

```py
#print(type(selArray)):
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
#print(selArray):
[<built-in function empty> -1.3868538952656493 0.7618747030055314
 -1.3868543839578398 0.7618746157390688 -1.3870217784863983
 0.7618121504051398 -1.3870217784863983 0.7618121504051398
 -1.3870217784863983 0.7618121504051398 -1.3869304105000566
...
 -1.3869682317849474 0.7617139232748376 -1.3869103741202438
 0.7616839734248734 -1.3868025127724706 0.7616153994385625
 -1.3869751607420777 0.761730050117126 -1.3866515941520503
 0.7615994122226143 -1.3866515941520503 0.7615994122226143]
```

Clearly, `[]` are missing around elements - and I don't understand where the `<built-in function empty>` comes from.

Comment: For starters, you want to _call_ `empty`: `
selArray = np.empty(some_shape)`

Comment: You can always use `np.where(condition you want to apply on first array)` to get the corresponding indices and then retrieve the elements from the second array.

Comment: Thanks so much! This works - I also found out something I'll add as a possible answer below..

Comment: What is the point of transposing when you can just select those elements directly? Besides, you don't even need to do that. Just `test_data[result_data > 1]` is enough

Comment: Hi Coldspeed, I added this as the correct answer (found it out myself a minute ago). Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be pretty straight forward:

```
selArray = test_data[result_data_>1]
```

See also possible solution in comment from Nain!